# How do I test my `useRef` implementation?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, jestjs

I'm trying to test a React component that I've created, where most of the rendering is delegated to D3 using a `useEffect`. For the `useEffect` to work properly I need to access a DOM element added by React within a `useRef`.

```
const Axis = ({
    ...
}) => {
    ...
    const scale = useSelector((s) => chartSelectors.scales.getScale(s, field));

    // React will own the axis containers, but D3 will own the axis themselves
    const axis = useRef(null);

    // Render the x-axis using D3
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(axis.current);
        
        if (axis.current && scale) {
            const selection = d3
                .select(axis.current)
                .transition()
                .duration(animationDuration);

            // Create the D3 axis renderer
            const d3Axis = getD3Axis(position);

            // Set some scale props
            d3Axis
                .scale(scale)
                .tickSizeInner(tickSizeInner)
                .tickSizeOuter(tickSizeOuter)
                .tickPadding(tickPadding);

            // Render the axis
            selection.call(d3Axis);
        }
    }, [
        axis,
        scale,
    ]);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Title position={position} title={title} fields={fields} />
            <g transform={transform}>
                {showGridlines ? <Gridlines position={position} scale={scale} /> : null}
                <g className="axis" ref={axis} />
            </g>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

In the above the key part is the `axis` ref which should be set by React and then the `useEffect` obviously needs to access `axis.current`. However when my test runs it's always `null`. If I add an artificial wait in my test, it'll render a 2nd time, also with the value of `null`.

Example test:

```
it('renders a left axis', async () => {
            const layer = { current: document.createElement('custom') };

            TestRenderer.act(() => {
                TestRenderer.create(
                    <Provider store={store}>
                        <Axis
                            layer={layer}
                            position="left"
                            fields={['y']}
                            showGridlines={false}
                        />
                    </Provider>,
                ).toJSON();
            });

            await new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(resolve, 500);
            });

            expect(layer.current).toMatchSnapshot();
        });
```

My question is, how can I get the `useRef` to work correctly for this test? I've tried mocking `useRef`, however as other parts of the app (in this case a Redux provider) use useRef internally, this breaks in other horrible ways in that the `useSelectors` fail.

Answer (score 0):

https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html#ideas suggests that this would work, but I ran into the exact same issue.

You could try to `awaitFor` the instance to finish rendering as `refs` are not set until after the render phase. I'm not sure if it will work. Perhaps it would be good to submit an issue to the React page.